# Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token and in a reasonable timeframe

Tags: c#, .net, google-api-dotnet-client

i'm having issue with google service account, the same about this post [Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token and in a reasonable timeframe", Uri:""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119238/errorinvalid-grant-descriptioninvalid-jwt-token-must-be-a-short-lived-tok), and i'm using the same procedure.

I'have checked time synchronization but the problem persists.
I've noticed that after the service is created by

```
var service = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "CRMpaolo",
        });
```

i can see that no token has been received/created, as the image below

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4KY0.png)

Is there any relation with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your time of assertion (iat) is the current time and date expressed as the number of seconds since 00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1970.
Make sure your expiration time for the assertion is set to 3600 seconds greater than your iat. Check out https://www.epochconverter.com/ to get current time in seconds.