# Firebase credentials error

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I got some error:

> Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the
>   \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access
>   token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token:
>   invalid_grant (Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token and in a
>   reasonable timeframe)\".

There are two likely causes: 
(1) your server time is not properly synced or 
(2) your certificate key file has been revoked.

To solve (1), re-sync the time on your server. 
To solve (2), make sure the key ID for your key file is still present at [firebase project](https://console.firebase.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project). If not, generate a new key file at [service account setting](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk).

When I try to use Firebase Admin SDK in Nodejs.

At my local computer it works, but when I try to use in AWS server, I got this error. Some tip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually because your server clock is out of sync. You will need to adjust and sync the clock on your AWS VM instance. See [Token must be a short-lived token and in a reasonable timeframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189612/token-must-be-a-short-lived-token-and-in-a-reasonable-timeframe)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, in my case I have a centos server in cloud and I used this article for solve the error: https://www.tecmint.com/set-accurate-server-time-in-centos/

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows and developing on the local environment, You can solve it by just setting your computer clock time to **set time automatically**. Both timezone and time should be set to **set automatically**. 
At least that's the single thing that worked for me in dev mode.

Comment: Do you know the solution for a Mac