# Spring Boot - Firebase Admin SDK - Notification

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I was trying to initialize the Admin SDK, but facing 400 bad request in service account initialization. It was working perfectly in my development windows environment, but when I deploy the same in linux, am facing this issue.

```
        SpringApplication.run(OrderApplication.class, args);

        FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(GlobalValue.serviceAccount);

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com").build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    }
```

I am reading the file path from property file.

`service.account=/home/service-account.json`

I was trying to send push notification, am facing issue at that time.

```
        try {
            MulticastMessage multicastMessage = MulticastMessage.builder().addAllTokens(lDeviceTokens)
                    .setNotification(new Notification(title, message)).build();

            BatchResponse response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendMulticast(multicastMessage);
            // See the BatchResponse reference documentation // for the contents of
            // response.
            System.out.println(response.getSuccessCount() + " messages were sent successfully");
        } catch (FirebaseMessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
```

Trace

```
. java: 141 S)
at org . apache . tomcat . util .neC . Socket ProcessorBase . run (Socket ProcessorBas
e . java : 49)
at java . concurrent . ThreadPooIExecuCor . runWorker (ThreadPooIExecuC01 .
java : 1149)
at java . concurrent . ThreadPooIExecucor$Worker . run (ThreadPooIExecuC01
. java : 624)
at org . apache . ComcaC . util . Chreads . TaskThread$WrappingRunnabIe . run (TaskTh
read . java : 61)
at java. lang . Thread. run (Thread. java : 7 48)
Caused by: java.io. IOExcepCion: Error getting access token for service account :
400 Bad Request
"error" • "invalid grant"
"error description" • "Invalid JWT: Token must be a short—lived token (60 minut
es) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check Y2ur iat and exp values and use a clock
with skew to account for clock differences between systems . "
at com.google . auth . oauCh2 . ServiceAccounCCredenCiaIs . refreshAccessToken ( S
erviceAccounCCredenCiaIs . java : 401)
at com.google . auth . oauCh2 . OAuth2CredenCiaIs . refresh (OAuth2CredenCiaIs . j a
va:181)
at com.google . auth . oauCh2 . OAuth2CredenCiaIs . geCRequesCMeCadaCa (OAuth2Cre
dentials . java : 167)
```

Comment: Can you post the full exception stack trace?

Comment: I think the system clock on your Linux machine is out of sync. That's preventing the OAuth2 flow from completing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please see these links if they help, looks to be a server time issue as you move to linux

[Google Client Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056381/google-client-invalid-jwt-token-must-be-a-short-lived-token)

[Token must be a short-lived token and in a reasonable timeframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189612/token-must-be-a-short-lived-token-and-in-a-reasonable-timeframe?lq=1)