# Error while accessing google cloud storage - google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.'})

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Client Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056381/google-client-invalid-jwt-token-must-be-a-short-lived-token)